# Typeof defeated by variable initializer

Tags: javascript

This code prints "undefined", as expected:

```
console.log(foo());

function foo() {
  return typeof a;
}
```

This one crashes with a "a is not defined" error:

```
const a = foo();

function foo() {
  return typeof a;
}
```

Is that a bug of V8 or an expected behavior?

Comment: I tried to change const to var and it does not error.

Comment: Yes, because `var` is hoisted, and so it ends up a bit like `let a; a = foo()`, which does not crash neither. The issue in my code is that `const a = foo()` is a single statement, which seems to semi-initialize the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

> The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s LexicalBinding is evaluated.

You are trying to access it in the middle of evaluating the LexicalBinding, which is forbidden.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the spec! I naively thought that right hand sides of assignments were evaluated before left hand sides, but it's more tricky than that indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Look, there is a circular pointing to each other. a calls foo, foo needs a.  So, what happens?

The easiest way to look at it: the = sign first executes the right hand side; then returns that result to whomever asked for the =.

So first foo is executed, then that result is given to var a ... but const a doesn't exist yet, while foo is being executed.

Comment: Nope, `typeof` is special in the sense that it does not throw if a variable does not exist (just type `typeof abc` in a console to see). So if the right hand side of the expression was first evaluated, the function should return "undefined", and assign it to `a`. The fact that it throws means that something is wrong.

Comment: yes in the first code a is not defined same as second code in that case if it is not yet exist